# deploy/debug app to iPod touch 2nd generation

Tags: ipod-touch, ios-4.2, xcode4.4

I'm new to iOS development and I try to get a simple HelloWorld app running on my iPod touch 2nd generation (iOS 4.2.1). For development I use a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4.1, as Xcode 4.5 apparently doesn't support the armv6 architecture anymore.
I created a new iOS Project (Single-View Application, no storyboards) and set the deployment target to 4.2. When I start it in the iPhone 5.1 Simulator it runs fine (only an empty view of course, printing "Hello World" will be my next step). However, if I try to run it on my iPod touch, I always get the following error message:

Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.

I tried to change the Architecture in the Build Settings from armv7 to armv6, but armv7 is the only option.
What can I do to get the app to run on my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution myself. In *Build Settings*, I entered *armv6* manually into *Valid Architectures* and *Architectures*.
The strange thing is: I can also enter *armv12* or *foobar* and it's still working. Only setting the architecture to *armv7* causes problems.